# How To use Exacttarget API to validate mobile numbers

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

Tried to find this in documentation. Had no luck.
I am just looking for a sample soap API call so that I could recognize if a given phone number is a mobile/cell phone and also a valid one. 
Can we achieve this using the exacttarget API ?

Thanks a lot for helping me out here.

Answer (score 4):

there isn't a method in the Fuel API to validate mobile numbers like there is for [validating email addresses](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/address/validateEmail.html).

However, there are a couple of solutions here. You can use a script to validate if the mobile number is in the correct format; Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) is a helpful library for validating international phone numbers.

However, if you want to verify that the mobile number **exists** (rather than validating the mobile number syntax), then you can use a verification API service [like this one](http://www.phone-validator.net/phone-number-online-validation-api.html) to check in real-time whether the phone number actually exists. In turn, this will minimize the quantity of "undeliverable" SMS messages that you send from MobileConnect.

Comment: Thanks for answering . Libphonenumber indeed gives useful information  however it does not tell us if the phone number is a cell phone or landline. for all the examples I tested, the result was "fixed_line_or_mobile".

Comment: Hello Ashish, according to the [readme](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber), `getNumberType` returns either: Fixed-line, Mobile, Toll-free, Premium Rate, Shared Cost, VoIP or Personal Numbers (whenever feasible). From the tests that I've run, `fixed_line` refers to a landline.

Answer (score 0):

Also from libphonenumber's readme, [Why did I get FIXED_LINE_OR_MOBILE as the type of my phone number?][1]https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/9942fbdf8bb5633a6509a60ba210a508b58e494f/FAQ.md#why-did-i-get-fixed_line_or_mobile-as-the-type-of-my-phone-number